# Armory on Linux

Tags: linux, mac, armory

Can I have my hot wallet running on Linux and my cold wallet running on a mac?

I am going to use armory as the bitcoin client, I wanted to use linux ( ubuntu 14.4) for the hot wallet and when signing transactions I put the usb into a mac.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no incompatibility with this setup.